# mostrar archivos html de un directorio en un php

Tags: php, html

Tengo un directorio con archivos html que son artículos(no tienen encabezado ni pie, quiero mostrar todos esos archivos html en un php llamado articulos.php con un link para acceder a ellos (el archivo articulos.php tiene encabezado y pie por require()

en fin lo que quiero es mostrar el articulo asi articulo.php?articulpo.html pero con el encabezado y pie del archivo articulo php

Comment: ¿Donde deseas mostrar el articulo `articulo.pho?articulpo.html` así?

Comment: Y el código fuente?

Comment: hola el el codigo fuente de articulo.php es <?php

require 'cabeza.php';

//lo que quiero hacer


require 'pie.php';


?> gracias por responder

Answer (score 3):

Para esta pregunta, voy a imaginar que tu sitio web tiene una estructura como ésta (seguramente sea un poco diferente, adaptar el código debería a tu estructura debería ser sencillo):

```
/
├ index.php
├ articulo.php
├ encabezado.php
├ pie.php
└ articulos/
     ├ articulo1.html
     ├ articulo2.html
     ├ articulo3.html
     ├ ...
```

En tu fichero `articulo.php` es donde tienes el encabezado y pie con un `require()`, entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Pasar por la cabecera el artículo que quieres que se incluya
2. Leer en el `$_GET` qué artículo
3. Añadir el html del artículo usando `require()` o `include()` (como ya estás haciendo para la cabecera y pie)

Considerando que el artículo se pasaria en la cabecera de la siguiente manera: `articulo.php?articulo=articulo1`, etonces eso se haría de la siguiente manera en `articulo.php`, :

```
<?php

    // incluimos la cabecera
    require("cabecera.php");

    // si se ha pasado el articulo y existe su fichero html
    $articulo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "articulo"); 
    if (isset($_GET["articulo"]) && file_exists("articulos/$articulo.html")) {
        // se incluye en la página
        require("./articulos/$articulo.html");
    } else {
        // si no se ha pasado id del artículo o no existe, se muestra un error
        echo "Artículo no especificado o no existente.";
    }

    // incluimos el pie
    require("pie.php");
```

Comment: hola amigo gracias por responder exactamente como respondiste es la estructura de mi web, probe , pero no me funciono, no cambie nada de tu codigo solo la ubicacion de archivo de varias formas pero salia " Artículo no especificado o no existente."

Comment: disculpa amigo funciona perfecto y encontré el error que fue mio, gracias

Comment: hola me di cuenta que si le doy requiere a cada archivo me los muestra todos al mismo tiempo en la url, gracias

Comment: No comprendo el error que te está dando ahora, ¿te muestra todos los artículos al mismo tiempo?

Answer (score 0):

```
$extension = ".html";



$directorio = '/tmp';
$dir = opendir($directorio);

while ($archivo = readdir($dir)){
 if (!is_dir($archivo)){//Validamos q no se abra otra carpeta
    if(strpos($archivo, $extension)){
      ///SE ENCONTRO ARCHIVO HTML
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco en qué consiste tu respuesta? Y formatear el código también.

Comment: hola amigo me sale un error "Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in" , gracias por la ayuda