# Como hacer require de todos los archivos .html de un directorio en php

Tags: php

tengo un directorio con archivos .html que son artículos para un post

hace poco me hice una pregunta en este sitio y me recomendaron este código que funciona perfecto para la pregunta .

```
<?php

// incluimos la cabecera
require("cabecera.php");

// si se ha pasado el articulo y existe su fichero html
if (isset($_GET["articulo"]) && file_exists("articulos/".$_GET["articulo"].".html")) {
    // se incluye en la página
    require("./articulos/articulo1.html");
} else {
    // si no se ha pasado id del artículo o no existe, se muestra un error
    echo "Artículo no especificado o no existente.";
}

// incluimos el pie
require("pie.php");
```

link de la pregunta: [mostrar archivos html de un directorio en un php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16734/mostrar-archivos-html-de-un-directorio-en-un-php)

ahora lo que necesito es hacer un require de todos los archivos .html de un directorio , para no tener que agregar el codigo por cada archivo.html nuevo que genere.

Comment: Si el código de la otra pregunta te funcionó, podrías aceptar la respuesta que mejor te funcionó.

Comment: ¿En qué parte deseas hacer solicitar todos los archivos html? Me refiero, teniendo en cuenta que estás obteniendo un parámetro por GET ¿ya no lo necesitas?

Comment: hola amigo gracias por comentar, funciono pero para solo un archivos pero para todos no funciona

Comment: Puedes encontrar varios ejemplos en [SO en Inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599670/how-to-include-all-php-files-from-a-directory), es un tema ya tratado. Solo deberías adaptar las extensiones `.php` a `.html`.

Comment: Vengo a la revisión y me quedo "ese código me suena" :P 
¿Lo que necesitas es que se muestren todos los artículos del directorio en la misma página?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
foreach (glob("./articulos/*.html") as $filename) {
    require($filename);
}
```

Comment: hola amigo, gracias por el código, pero me di cuenta que el script de arriba solo sirve para un archivo, me prodrías ayudar con las dos preguntas, gracias de antemano